# updating or changing a value automatically in MS Access

Tags: microsoft-access

In access 2007
how can I go about it if I want to (for example create two tables “stock” and “customer) and I want to create a particular field that'll be present in both fields (i.e a field like “availability” which will probably be a yes/no data type)

I want this field to be present in both tables, now, if I have a good that is stored in the “stock” table and the customer wants to purchase, I already have a lookup field that will help me access those goods alongside with the properties all from the “stock” table,

But the challenge now is, how do I go about it if I want the availability of a good which I already selected from “stock” table to automatically change the value of the availability to a “NO” value

The previous paragraph talks about the challenge am encountering, though I already successfully done everything but I have to go back to stock and update manually (i.e set the value of a particular goods to “NO”) which is exactly what I don't want, I want to do something better, i.e make it automatically update in the “stock” table

Is there something I am missing, or is there a code that ll be responsible for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [issues with referential integrity (access 2007)](http://superuser.com/questions/888583/issues-with-referential-integrity-access-2007)

Comment: Customer table should just have your customer data. Stock (inventory) table should have just your inventory details and possibly inventory counts. Your third table should be a sales table that uses customer table data with inventory data. When you create the sales order, this is when the quantity gets deducted from your stock table. In the same process, you can update the availability field to indicate if the product is still in stock or not. You have not clarified if you are using VBA, forms (which is a StackOverflow question), or some specific way to update data.